# Row with non-event times Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to put a standard text on lines that do not have events?

[image]

Comment: There are ways, but why do you want to? It would get very cluttered. I see you already have a key/legend on the right hand side of the calendar. I would suggest that should be enough to explain the purpose of each area of the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `title` to a `background event`

```
{ 
    id: '1', 
    resourceId: '123', 
    start: '2021-03-07T02:00:00', 
    end: '2021-03-07T06:00:00',
    rendering: 'background',
    title: 'my background title'
}
```

then in `eventRender` you could output it to the screen, inside the event block

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    if (event.rendering == 'background') {
        element.append(event.title);
    }
}
```

then you could use CSS to gain control of how it looks.

[image: example background event]

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events